# Problems with having the same DNS namespace

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

What are the possible issues caused by having two separate DNS infrastructure (not just different dns servers but running on different platforms as well) hosting the same DNS namespace without isolating either one's presence on the network.

Altria

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be an issue doing this assuming the clients were appropriately configured, but in reality why would you want to do this? I think you would be better off implementing split horizon dns.

[Split horizon dns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything offhand. Presumably, each DNS client is configured to use one or the other DNS infrastructure, right?

The two "sets" of DNS servers don't need to interact with each other and won't be aware of each others presence so the only drawback I can see is keeping the two DNS infrastuctures in sync, if in fact you have a need to do that.

Can you give us more info on your setup, such as why you want or need to have this?